# Binding visibility of control inside listbox to a property not contained in the itemsource collection

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, listbox, itemtemplate

I have a listbox with a datatemplate that holds a number of controls bound to my collection.

I want to bind the visibility of one of the controls to a property defined in the class , an instance of which is set to datacontext in code behind.This property is not a member of collection which is item source of the listbox.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods to do this.

- Set Binding.Source to the data context you want. You could add the DataContext to the resources and use `{Binding Source={StaticResource ?}}`
- Give the element that has the data context you need a name and use `{Binding DataContext.Property, ElementName=?}`. This might not be applicable if your ItemTemplate is in a resource.
- Add the property you want to the items in the collection either directly or create a wrapper class.